# didSelectItemAtIndexPath内でカスタムセルを取得する

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

CollectionViewのCellをタップした時に、TwiterアプリのカメラロールのようにsubViewをCellに追加する、といった処理を実装しようとしています。
そう思い、このような処理を書いてみました。

```
- (CameraRollCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CameraRollCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CameraRollCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell selectPhoto];
}
```

UICollectionViewCell`を継承したカスタムクラスを用意し、タップされた時にそのCellを取得。取得後、カスタムセルが持つsubViewを追加するメソッドを呼び出しています。

が、恐らく`cellForItemAtIndexPath:`ではカスタムクラスのCellでの取得が出来ないので弾かれてしまいます…。

そこで質問なのですが、

1. `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`でカスタムクラスのCellを取得することは出来ますか？
2. もっと効率的な実装方法はありますか？

ご回答、よろしくお願い致します。

補足
- StoryBoardは使っておりません。コードのみでの実装です。

Comment: `indexPathForCell`ではなく`cellForItemAtIndexPath:`を使ったコードしか提示されていないようですが?また「カスタムクラスのCellでの取得が出来ない」のは、`collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`の時点で、既にカスタムクラスになっていない可能性が高いと思います。`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`でカスタムクラスを取得するための設定は正しく行われていますか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
`cellForItemAtIndexPath:`の誤りでした。修正致します。
`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`の設定、少し試してみます。
改めてコメントありがとうございました。

Comment: `viewDidLoad`内で`[self.collectionView registerClass:[CameraRollCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cameraRollCellID];`を追加したら無事動作しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 少しでもお役に立てたのであれば嬉しいです。お時間が取れるようなら、解決方法をご自身で「回答」として投稿すること(さらに、解決のマーキングをすること)も考えてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad`内に`[self.collectionView registerClass:[CameraRollCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cameraRollCellID];`を追加したら無事動作しました。
コメントをして下さった方、ありがとうございました。